# Migration tools from telligent to SharePoint

Tags: migration

Hi, I have a website which runs on the telligent platform. I need to migrate it to SharePoint 2013. Can you please let me know what the tools are available for it and pros and cons of them.

Comment: Sorry, this is really very broad. Can you indicate what type of website and give a little more information? Not sure this can be answered in it's current form and may need to be closed, sorry.

Comment: Please, even if English is not your first language, use some punctuation. This will help a lot with making your question easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [Metalogix](http://www.metalogix.com/help/Migration-Manager-for-SharePoint/Blog-and-Wiki-Edition/001_GettingStarted/010_Connecting2Telligent.htm) can migrate data from Telligent to Sharepoint.

> Supported Source Systems 
> MediaWiki - Versions 1.12 and later. 
>   Confluence - Any versions before v.4.0 that have SOAP API version 1,
>   and versions 4.0 through to 5.1.  
> WordPress - Any versions that
>   support XML-RPC API.  
> Atom Feed - All.  
> Telligent - Any version that
>   supports MetaWeblog API.  
> Other Blogs and Wikis - Any other blogs or
>   Wikis that support MetaWeblog API.  
> RSS Feeds - All.

Pro: Professionally developed application with support
Con: Will cost you some money

Comment: Good or bad, this actually appears to be the only tool available.

Comment: This could be done in few clicks using Telligent WebParts for SharePoint.

Comment: Why the down vote? (presumably @Warlock) The link provided shows data can be migrated which is what they want, not maintain 2 environments, 1 to house the data and another to surface the data.

Comment: This seems to infer that MetaWeblog API been around since Community Server 2, http://weblogs.asp.net/lhunt/archive/2006/05/22/CommunityServer-2.0-_2600_-MetaWeblog-API.aspx.

Comment: add an underscore to both sides of the 2600, _2600_, the markdown isn't working right. The question was a tool to migrate off, telling them to stay on both systems and pay both licensing costs is not practical when they want to leave the platform.

Comment: I have not used their migration tool, I have used some of their other products with no issues in the past. Their product information says they can migrate from Telligent which again is what the OP was asking about. THis link specifically says Telligent apart from the any system supporting metaweblog or RSS, http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Content-Matrix/Tech-Specs.aspx.

Comment: As I found from your link they are support only blogs. What about forums, wikis, galleries, user profiles and so on?

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to migrate data physically, because Telligent provides SharePoint WebParts to display forums/blogs/wikis. You just need to install this web parts and configure your integration.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use some 3-rd party tools like from ShareGate, Metalogic or Avepoint.
All have many similar features. What about Pros and Cons - it's better to test all of them and find what tool is better suites your needs.
Good luck!